# Invalid hook call when using useQuery

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have this useQuery call to fetch my sample data.

```
import {Weather} from "../../Models/Weather/Weather";
import axios from "axios";
import {useQuery} from "react-query";

export const getWeatherForecastKey = () => "weather";

export const useWeatherForecast = () =>
    useQuery<Weather[]>(getWeatherForecastKey(), () =>
        axios
            .get(
                `https://localhost:44471/api/weatherforecast`
            )
            .then((response) => response.data)
    );
```

And Im trying to call it like this on one of my pages.

```
import React from 'react';

import {useWeatherForecast} from "../../Hooks/queries/useWeatherForecast";

const RegisterPage: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const {data: weather, isLoading: isLoadingWeather, isError: isErrorWeather} = useWeatherForecast();
    
    if(isLoadingWeather) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

    if(!weather || isErrorWeather) return <h1>Error...</h1>
 
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 id="tableLabel">Weather forecast</h1>
            <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default RegisterPage;
```

HomePage is used like this in Router. I can load the HomePage when I delete the hook from it.

```
const AppRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/register',
  element: <RegisterPage />
  }
];

export default AppRoutes;
```

But Im keep getting this following error. Am I missing something or what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: How is `RegisterPage` used?

Comment: Sorry I don't see anything invalid about the code you've posted here. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: what kind of router is this using? my guess is  that `element: <RegisterPage />` should actually be `element: RegisterPage`